# colored frame for a tabular column

Tags: tables, border

I have a problem, I want to make a two sided frame in Beamer.
It works really well, but I need a border around the right column of the table. It should be around the colored background of that side only. (which is not included in this code, because it need additional commands, which arent necessary to that code)

EDIT: Please note, that I only care about the frame around

I hope someone can help me!
Thank you in advance!

```
\documentclass[14pt, aspectratio=169, usenames, dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.5em}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{steps to work through}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{-0.5cm}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{p{8cm} p{8cm}}
    \raisebox{-.89\height}
    &
    <2->{\small
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<3-> Step 1
            \item<4-> Step 2
            \item<5-> Step 3
            \item<6-> Step 4
        \end{itemize}
    }
\end{tabular*}
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Please post a full compilable code. This oone, even completed, doesn't compile

Comment: Sorry Bernard, realized it too late!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand the question but let me try. Is this what you want?

[image]

```
\documentclass[14pt, aspectratio=169, usenames, dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.5em}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{steps to work through}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{-0.5cm}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{p{8cm} p{8cm}}
    \raisebox{-.89\height}
    &
    <2->{\begin{tcolorbox}\small
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<3-> Step 1
            \item<4-> Step 2
            \item<5-> Step 3
            \item<6-> Step 4
        \end{itemize}\end{tcolorbox}
    }
\end{tabular*}
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I need, I completely forget tcolorbox..     As you may see I want to blend it in in the second frame of the presentation-slide, and I don't understand where stuff above the box comes from. Can you help me with that too?  A big thank you anyway!!

Comment: Nevermind, just solved it with \visible